# What does conditional たら add to 未然形+う+とする?

Tags: conditionals

Do the following sentences differ in meaning?  I understand that conditional たら adds the meaning of simultaneous action, but does the meaning of the sentence really change without たら?

> 寝ようとした、電話が掛かってきた。I was about to go to bed, and the phone rang.
>
> 寝ようとした**ら**、電話が掛かってきた。**When** I was about to go to bed, and the phone rang.

Comment: Hmm 「寝ようとした、電話が掛かってきた。」 is two separate, independent sentences. To turn them into a single sentence you'd need something to connect them, like a conjunctive particle or the continuative form of a verb, auxiliary, etc.

Comment: As Chocolate said, the first example is actually two separate sentences. The -たら in the second sentence links them together to form a single sentence. The form -たら can be used as a conditional or to mean when.